# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable encountered while performing some data preprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am encountering an error while checking the shape of variable x

```
#imports
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes

#loading the dataset
dbt=load_diabetes()
#exploring the dataset
dbt.keys()
#Creating a dataframe that contains all the data
df_feat=pd.DataFrame(dbt['data'],columns=dbt['feature_names'])
#data preprocessing
x=df_feat
y=dbt['target']
x.shape()
y.shape()
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 4):

`shape` is just an attribute, not a method. 
Use `x.shape` instead of `x.shape()`.